# Busboy hangs (in express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, file-transfer, busboy

I tried to use Busboy in express framework. I want to use it directly without multer just to learn how it works. I stoped on the first example and don't know where the error is. It's quite hard for me to investigate because it just hangs with no error message.

I copied the code from demo from URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy

And pasted it into my express application as follows:

```
app.get('/files/new', function(req, res) {
    //res.send(req.headers)
    res.send('<html><head></head><body>\
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/files">\
     <input type="text" name="textfield"><br />\
     <input type="file" name="filefield"><br />\
     <input type="submit">\
   </form>\
 </body></html>')
})


app.post('/files', function(req, res) {
    console.log("files post")
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
      file.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
      });
      file.on('end', function() {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
      });
    });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('Done parsing form!');
      res.send("Done")
    });
})
```

I receives following output in the console each time I send the file:

```
Server started....
files post
```

The browser is hanged.

Can anyone point me what may cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason why it hanged. I mistekaly forgot close the connection, below lines:

```
busboy.on('finish', function() {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
  res.end("Done parsing form!");
});
```